# ActiveRecord Validations : String added to error message in locales

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-i18n

I'm trying customize validation error messages using i18n.

Let's say I have an Address model that validates the presence of a `zip_code`.
My `config/locales/activerecord.fr.yml` looks like this

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        address:
          attributes:
            civility:
              blank: "Some message"
```

The issue if I fail the validation, the error message I'l have in `@address.errors.full_messages` will be:

`"Zip code Some message"`

Why does `Zip code` gets added to my error message ? And how can I avoid this behaviour ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add:

```
errors:
  format: "%{message}"
```

This way you will just show error message with out attribute name.

Edit: this should be added to `config/locales/fr.yml` and not `config/locales/activerecord.fr.yml` (which also has `errors:`)

Comment: It does not work. I'm using `rails 5.1.3` if that can be of any help.

Comment: By Rails guides it is stile the same:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#overview-of-other-built-in-methods-that-provide-i18n-support

ActiveModel::Errors#full_messages prepends the attribute name to the error message using a separator that will be looked up from errors.format (and which defaults to "%{attribute} %{message}").

As you can see here: 
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/locale/en.yml

Answer (score 1):

Found a [gem](https://github.com/nanamkim/custom-err-msg) which will solve your purpose

With the help of this gem, You just need to start the locale message with a caret and it shouldn't display the attribute name in the message.

A model defined as:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

with the following en.yml:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        item:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "^You can't create an item without a name."
```

`item.errors.full_messages` will display:

```
#You can't create an item without a name
```

instead of the usual

```
#Name You can't create an item without a name
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use:

```
@address.errors.messages[:zip_code] # or @address.errors[:zip_code]
#=> ['Some message']
```